# what happens to the foreground service when associated notification is removed?

Tags: android, service

I have  a service running in foreground . I m looking for a way to stop the service from running in foreground when the user touches the notification. I understrand that the foreground service can be removed by calling the stopforeground function . I referred to the android dev docs about foreground service, but it does not mention anything about the behavior of the foreground service when the notification associated with it gets removed. So my question are
1)It is possible to stop a foreground service by creating a notification that clears when the user touches it ?
2)How can one be sure that the service is not running in foreground anymore?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
public final void stopForeground (boolean removeNotification)

Added in API level 5
Remove this service from foreground state, allowing it to be killed if more memory is needed.

Parameters
removeNotification  If true, the notification previously provided to startForeground(int, Notification) will be removed. Otherwise it will remain until a later call removes it (or the service is destroyed).
```

Basically, it says that if a service is destroyed then its notification will automatically be removed as well. But if a service is simply stopped and the argument provided is `false`, then the notification will remain until a later call removes it or the service is destroyed.

So in your callback for the notification, you can include a call like `stopForeground(true)`, so that the service is stopped and the notification is removed as well.